# Guaranteeing 0 at same level on left and right y axes (Python matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to overlap two functions which have different scales.

Since they also both tend to go from positive to negative, I think it'd be visually nicer if I could guarantee that the 0 level on both axes line up.

Since I don't necessarily know the scale of both functions ex-ante (it changes with parameters that I change from time to time higher up in my code), I'm kind of stuck with how to proceed--mainly because I'm pretty new to Python.

Here's a toy example that kind of gets the point.

Any suggestions for how to guarantee they line up?
I imagine it should be pretty simple, but I'm drawing a blank as to what types of functions to be exploring.

```
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2=ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(np.random.normal(loc=np.random.rand(),size=100),'r-')
ax2.plot(np.random.normal(loc=10*np.random.rand(),size=100),'b-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Say you're plotting `f1` and `f2`.  Can you guarantee that `max(f1)*min(f1)<0` and `max(f2)*min(f2)<0`?

Comment: Yes. In my case, f1 is two functions, g1 and g2, both of which are constrained to be in [0,1], but i'm plotting g1 and -g2 (and there's always strictly positive part of both)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though gboffi's answer does provide A solution, I'm realizing there are many correct solutions to this problem. In particular, I'll outline 4 potential options--the final is the most general (and likely the least useful), but subsumes the others.

I'm still going to focus on the case where we want the axes to align at y (dependent variable)=0. The approach here should be straightforward to adjust to other levels--with messier formulas, but largely identical complexity.

Let's fix ideas to explain what these options are. The key is to think of 0 as a weighted average of the extrema on the left (L) and right (R) axes. Specifically, there is a weight wL such that 0 = wL*ML+(1-wL)(-mL), where ML is the left upper limit and mL is the (magnitude of) the left lower limit (which is negative). Specifically, wL=mL/(mL+ML). Similarly, wR=mR/(mR+MR).

The setup is similar to gboffi's answer, and is the same for all 4 options:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

grid = np.linspace(0,5,1000)
a = 1.0*np.sin(grid)+0.6
b = 8.0*np.cos(grid)-5.0+3*np.sin(5*grid)-5

fig,axL = plt.subplots()
lL, = axL.plot(grid,a,'r-', label='axL')
plt.legend()
axR = axL.twinx()
lR, = axR.plot(grid,b,'b-', label='axR')

mL, ML = axL.get_ylim() ; Lticks = axL.get_yticks()
mR, MR = axR.get_ylim() ; Rticks = axR.get_yticks()

if mL*ML > 0 : error()
if mR*MR > 0 : error()
```

Option 1: Force y=0 halfway up either axis.

```
ML = max(ML,abs(mL))
mL = min(-ML,mL)

MR = max(MR,abs(mR))
mR = min(-MR,mR)
```

[image: Option 1]

Option 2: Force wL' = wR (change the left axis, keep the right axis the same; this is gboffi's answer)

```
wL = abs(mL)/(ML+abs(mL))
wR = abs(mR)/(MR+abs(mR))

ML = (mL*MR/mR if wR<=wL else ML      )
mL = (mL       if wR<=wL else ML*mR/MR)
```

[image: Option 2]

Option 3: Force wR' = wL (change the right axis, keep the left axis the same)

```
wL = abs(mL)/(ML+abs(mL))
wR = abs(mR)/(MR+abs(mR))

MR = (mR*ML/mL if wL<=wR else MR      )
mR = (mR       if wL<=wR else MR*mL/ML)
```

[image: Option 3]

Option 4: Force wR'=wL'=w (change both axes, force 0 to be w% of the way to the top of the plot)

```
w = .42
wL = abs(mL)/(ML+abs(mL))
wR = abs(mR)/(MR+abs(mR))

ML = ((w-1)/w*mL if w<=wL else ML        )
mL = (mL         if w<=wL else w/(w-1)*ML)
MR = ((w-1)/w*mR if w<=wR else MR        )
mR = (mR         if w<=wR else w/(w-1)*MR)
```

[image: Option 4]

The rest of the code is again identical to gboffi's:

```
axL.set_ylim(mL,ML) ; axL.set_yticks(Lticks)
axR.set_ylim(mR,MR) ; axR.set_yticks(Rticks)
for ax, c in ((axL,'r'),(axR,'b')):
    [lbl.set_color(c) for lbl in ax.get_yticklabels()]

axL.grid(color='black', axis='x')
axL.grid(color='red',   axis='y')
axR.grid(color='blue',  axis='y')

plt.legend((lL,lL),('axL','axR'))
plt.show()
```

Option 4 subsumes everything, but may be most useless--I can't imagine a situation in which we'd want w outside, say, (.4,.6)--and anything but options 2 and 3 creates white space on both axes (whereas options 2/3 guarantee at least one axis is the same as it was originally).

As far as choosing among options 1-3, it depends on the situation--it's really a matter of obscuring information, ultimately. Which graph suffers less from being squeezed to fit the scale of the other? Here, we might want to focus on the right-hand graph, because there is much more going on. The neutral position--w=.5, i.e., Option 1--may be best if you have no idea ex-ante what either graph looks like.

EDIT: As concerns the idea raised by gboffi below to use Option 4 to minimize the proportion of white space induced by this procedure, the optimum is always either w=wR or w=wL, as described by this graph:

[image: White Space-Minimizing Weight w]

Here is a writeup.

[image: Minimizer Solution]

Comment: I'm up in the air about whether to highlight this or @gboffi 's as the correct answer--his is more concise; I'm worried this might be a bit long-winded. I'll let the community decide.

Comment: Commenting option no.2 you say «[this option] change the left axis,
keep the right axis the same; this is gboffi's answer».  This is what
happened with my test functions, but I coded so that one of your
options 2 and 3 is choosen, based on leaving alone the y axis with the
largest excursion, so that in the rescaled plot you have a feeling of
the relative amplitudes.

Comment: You said «Which graph suffers less from being squeezed to fit the
scale of the other? The neutral position--w=.5, i.e., Option 1--may be
best if you have no idea ex-ante what either graph looks like.».  But
when you reassign `ylim`s you are ex-post, as the axes are both
prepared and you know exactly everything about them (I feel that my
idea, to rescale the yaxis with the less variation, is the better
choice because the added whitespace lets you have an immediate feeling
of the relative size and at the same time doesn't enforce the same
scale on both axes).

Comment: Option no. 4 leads to the idea of optimizing the weight `w` so that
the total amount of whitespace on both axes is minimized, but I don't
know at the moment if it makes really sense, I'd have to think about
it...

Comment: You're right--your solution was robust enough to subsume cases 2&3. I was being hasty. I shied away from the excursion-based determination, as you put it, because the left and right axes don't have the same units--so concerns about amplitude don't have much meaning. That's what I was getting at when talking about not knowing what the graph looks like / choosing based on variation. I'll edit it to provide a better example.

Comment: About optimizing, I just slogged through the math and it doesn't seem to have added much insight--the answer is (almost) always to use one of the original scales. Only if the scales add up to one, the proportion of white space is identical as long as we choose w between the original scales (no intuition jumps to mind why this is the case).

Comment: :-( ፨ Not really, your answer is DEFINITELY better than mine…!

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

I have updated my code to reflect my comments on leaving alone the function with the greatest range and rescaling the other one, and also about the `yticks`.

While at it, I throw in also the legends (note that you have to save the lines you plot, the comma is essential) and grids of differing colors.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 1.0*np.sin(np.linspace(0,5,51))+0.6
b = 8.0*np.cos(np.linspace(0,5,51))-5.0

fig,ax1 = plt.subplots()
l1, = ax1.plot(a,'r-', label='ax1')
plt.legend()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
l2, = ax2.plot(b,'b-', label='ax2')

y1mn, y1mx = ax1.get_ylim() ; y1ticks = ax1.get_yticks()
y2mn, y2mx = ax2.get_ylim() ; y2ticks = ax2.get_yticks()

if y1mn*y1mx > 0 : error()
if y2mn*y2mx > 0 : error()

d1 = y1mx-y1mn
d2 = y2mx-y2mn

r1=-y1mx/y1mn
r2=-y2mx/y2mn

if d1>d2:
    if r1>r2:
        y2mx = -y2mn*r1
    else:
        y2mn = -y2mx/r1
else:
    if r2>r1:
        y1mx = -y1mn*r2
    else:
        y1mn = -y1mx/r2

ax1.set_ylim(y1mn,y1mx) ; ax1.set_yticks(y1ticks)
ax2.set_ylim(y2mn,y2mx) ; ax2.set_yticks(y2ticks)
for ax, c in ((ax1,'r'),(ax2,'b')):
    [lbl.set_color(c) for lbl in ax.get_yticklabels()]

ax1.grid(color='black', axis='x')
ax1.grid(color='red',   axis='y')
ax2.grid(color='blue',  axis='y')

plt.legend((l1,l2),('ax1','ax2'))
plt.show()
```

gives you

[image: Updated plot]

<del>you may want to intervene on the y ticks also, but I think this can get you started.</del>

<del>In retrospect, it seems to me that one must take into account which function has the maximum range and scale the other one, but again, this should be sufficient to get you started...</del>

Comment: yes, silly as it is, i didn't know about the get_ylim function. this works great, thanks!

Comment: `Axes` have literally(?) hundreds of get/set methods... I have upgraded a bit my solution to reflect my comments, plus some bells and whistles. You may want to have a look, ciao

Comment: I'm realizing there's no objectively right answer to the question as posed. I'm going to post a slightly more general version of the solution than you've given that covers (what I see as) all the possible choices to address the problem I've got in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the same grid for both left and right plots. Therefore the left size is fixed then:

```
rticks = np.array(lticks) / lticks[-1] * rticks[-1]
```

if the right size is fixed then:

```
lticks = np.array(rticks) / rticks[-1] * lticks[-1]
```